# Find the kth smallest element in an unsorted array of non-negative integers

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays

I need to find the kth smallest element in an unsorted array of non-negative integer.

kth smallest element is the minimum possible n such that there are at least kth elements <= n.

The rub here is that the array is read only so it can't be modified. Also i have to do it in constant space.

Can anybody help come up with the most optimal solution ?

Comment: What's wrong with brute-forcing it in $O(nk)$ time and $O(k)$ space?

Comment: @greybeard you mean $O(nk)$ time and $O(1)$ space?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks: while I can see that it doesn't matter with a "Real RAM", I'd frown iterating the input more than once, hence $k$ candidates in preference over one (and a count).

Comment: OP mentioned they wanted an algorithm running in *constant* space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple randomized algorithm running in expected $O(n\log n)$ time. The algorithm is a variant of the better known algorithm QuickSelect.

The algorithm maintains a pair of values $a \leq b$, initially $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ (or, the minimum and maximum values of the array). At each round, it chooses a uniformly random element $c$ in the range $[a,b]$ from the array, and computes its order statistics, i.e., the value $\ell$ such that $c$ is the $\ell$th smallest element in the array.

- If $\ell = k$, then we return $c$.
- If $\ell > k$, we replace $b$ with $c$.
- If $\ell < k$, we replace $a$ with $c$.

If $a = b$ then we return $a$. Otherwise, we continue for one more iteration.

Each iteration takes time $O(n)$, so in order to estimate the running time of the algorithm, we need to estimate the number of rounds. We will keep track of the number of "live" elements, initially $n$. The algorithm ends when the number of live elements gets down to 1 (or even sooner, if there are repeated elements).

Let us denote by $n_t$ the number of elements after $t$ rounds, so that $n_0 = n$. The exact distribution of $n_{t+1}$ given $n_t$ depends on the location of the $k$th order statistics among the live elements. Let us suppose that the $k$th order statistics is the $\ell$th live element. Without loss of generality, $\ell \leq (n_t+1)/2$. Suppose that we choose the $r$th order statistic, so $r$ is uniform over $1,\ldots,n_t$. Then:

- If $r = 1,\ldots,\ell-1$ then $n_{t+1} = n_t - (r-1)$.
- If $r = \ell$ then $n_{t+1} = 0$.
- If $r = \ell+1,\ldots,n_t$ then $n_{t+1} = r$.

In total, the expected value of $n_{t+1}$ is
$$
\frac{1}{n_t} [(n_t + \cdots + n_t-\ell+2) + (\ell+1 + \cdots + n_t)].
$$
The number of summands is constant, and the worst case is when $\ell = (n_t+1)/2$, in which case the expected value of $n_{t+1}$ is
$$
\frac{(\frac{n_t+1}{2}+n_t)\frac{n_t-1}{2}}{n_t} \leq \frac{3}{4}n_t.
$$
Induction shows that $\mathbb{E}[n_t] \leq (3/4)^t n$, and so the expectation drops below 1 for $t = O(\log n)$.

While this doesn't quite show that the expected number of iterations is $O(\log n)$, more refined arguments do, and they moreover show that the number of iterations is $O(\log n)$ with high probability.

---

Here are some hints on how to implement the algorithm. The crucial step is to choose a uniformly random element $c$ in the range $[a,b]$ from the array. There are at least two ways to go about it, both taking $O(n)$:

**Reservoir sampling**

1. Initialize $N = 0$ and $X = \bot$.
2. Go over all elements of the array. For each element $x$, if $a \leq x \leq b$:

   - Increment $N$.
   - Replace $X$ with $x$ with probability $1/N$.
3. Return $X$.

**Linear scan**

1. Count the number of elements in the array between $a$ and $b$ — say the answer is $N$.
2. Draw a random integer $i$ between 1 and $N$.
3. Go over the array again, and return the $i$th element between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The analysis, as written, actually only works in the case of distinct elements. But the algorithm should work with similar efficiency in the general case as well.

Comment: How do you pick an element $c$ "uniformly random in the range $[a,b]$ from the array" in $O(n)$? Does that mean that each element of the array is equally likely to be picked, or the value is equally distributed in $[a,b]$?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401375/how-would-you-pick-a-uniform-random-element-in-linked-list-with-unknown-length

Comment: I mention this because it's a nontrivial part of the full algorithm. It should be made more obvious in the answer if reservoir sampling is being used.

Comment: You don't have to do we reservoir sampling, though it's certainly a possibility. Instead, you can count the eligible elements, draw an index, and then go over the array again to figure d the chosen element.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for the answer. I am having trouble implementing the logic which you have mentioned. Think you can share a pseudo code or better a python code so that i can better understand the solution. Thanks

Comment: This isn't a coding site, so I won't share any python code. What part of my algorithm are you having trouble with?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i am having trouble calculating the rth order statistics.

Comment: The variable $r$ only appears in the analysis of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for an obvious answer that satisfies the requirements.

You can loop through the array and find the smallest element ($x$) and how many times it occurs ($y$).

In the next loop you find the next smallest element ($x'_{>x}$) and add how many times it occurs to the count $y$.

Continue until $y$ reaches $k$. It takes $O(nk)$ time and constant space.